# Return bool function with an aliased column name in PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this pgsql function that checks if a person exists based on given `personid`. This function returns `bool` accordingly. From my query, I get the following:

[image]

However, I want the resulting column to have an `alias` so it's more readable among our developers. So instead of getting `func_util__check_basicinfo`, I want it to be `person_exists`.

Also the reason why the function is named this way is for our convention purpose.

Here's my query for this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION profile.func_util__check_basicinfo(person_id integer)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        return exists (
            select 1
            from profile.person_basicinfo pb
            where pb.personid = person_id
        );
    END;
$function$
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function's definition doesn't and can't define an alias. You will need to use the alias in the query where you use the function:

```
select func_util_check_basicinfo(...) as person_exists
from ...
```

By default a column will be named after the source in the query. So the column name always defaults to the function's name (this is true for all functions in Postgres). If you don't want to specify the column alias manually in every query, your only option is to rename the function to `person_exists()`  (which I would find a much better name than the existing one to begin with)

Comment: Woah that's so right, should be aliased during func call... but yes you are right too naming the function to `person_exists()` makes much more sense. This is what I actually ended up doing and set aside our naming convention for this case... Thanks man!